# What does the following code do?

Tags: c, process, fork

Including the initial parent process, how many processes are created by the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
     /* fork a child process */
     fork();

     /* fork a child process */
     fork();

     /* and  fork another */
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Cristian I would have marked it as duplicated if only I had enough repo there :)

Comment: How would you go about demonstrating the answer?  You'd need to add some `printf()` statements; you might use `printf("PID %d\n", (int)getpid());` before, after and between the `fork()` calls, possibly with `fflush(stdout);` calls too (there's a whole other set of questions on what happens if the output is going to terminal vs output is going to file).

Answer (score -1):

simple answer is :

```
fork() faild too many processes.
```

no count is done to check after the retrun of fork() if you are in father or son, so forking will goeis on until you hit nproc, or lack ressources.

Comment: No, there's a finite (and small) set of processes created (8 including the initial process)

Comment: This is **NOT** a fork() bomb!

Comment: Have you actually run the program to see what happens?

Comment: Obvoiusly, I failed the test :-(